# opencart - How to get the category title on the product details page?

Tags: php, opencart

I want to display the category title on the products details page. I could do it by displaying the last breadcrumb (which would be the category), but if I do that it won't show up if I access the product from the "specials" page (since it doesn't display the categories in the breadcrumb - just "Home > Product2").

**How would I go about getting the category ID so I can then pull the title from that?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution:

In /catalog/controller/product/product.php

somewhere after line 129 add:

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);

if ($categories)
   $categories_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($categories[0]['category_id']);

$this->data['category_title'] = $categories_info['name'];
```

This will get the product's first category title (since a product may be in more than one category).

After that, in the product.tpl `echo $category_title;`

Comment: Please note this gets the first top-level category, not the first parent category